# Blowing up along a point in the special fiber

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Let $p$ be a prime number, and let $\mathbb{Z}_p$ be the $p$-adic numbers. In concrete terms, what is the blow up of $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{Z}_p} = \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ along the closed subscheme corresponding to the ideal $(p,x)$?

Edit: For context, this question comes up in the study of Néron models, but few authors bother to spell out all the details. Since my training in classical algebraic geometry is somewhat rudimentary it's not entirely clear to me how the construction goes. I looked in some standard references on algebraic geometry, but most of the examples are in the geometric context where one works over a field, and I don't immediately see how to convert these computations to my setting.

I think the answer to this question should not be difficult, but I also could not find any similar examples worked out in detail (although I may not have looked hard enough). It might be helpful to more people than myself to have the answer available here.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I know it's a simple question, but isn't that the purpose of this site? I could not find any "arithmetic" examples of blow ups worked out anywhere so I thought it might be beneficial for others too if I asked it here.

Comment: I added more context. Please consider reopening the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually wondered a similar question a while ago in the context of integral models of $\mathbb P^1$, so here are my thoughts.

The blow-up of a scheme $X$ by a sheaf of ideals $\mathcal I$, by definition, is the relative Proj $\underline{\mathrm{Proj}}_X(\bigoplus_{n\ge0}\mathcal I^n)$. Thus your blow up is
$$\mathrm{Proj}(\mathbb Z_p[x]\oplus(p,x)\oplus(p^2,px,x^2)\oplus\cdots).$$
The ring has generators $X_1:=p$ and $Y_1:=x$ in degree $1$ with relations $xX_1=pY_1$. Thus the blow-up is isomorphic to the sub-scheme of $\mathbb A_{\mathbb Z_p}^1\times\mathbb P_{\mathbb Z_p}^1$, with coordinates $(x,(X_1:Y_1))$ cut out by $xX_1=pY_1$.

The special fiber over $p$ is the subscheme of
$$\mathbb A^1_{\mathbb F_p}\times\mathbb P_{\mathbb F_p}^1$$
cut out by the equation $xX_1=0$, i.e., it is the union $\mathbb A^1\cup\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb F_p}$ where $0\in\mathbb A^1_{\mathbb F_p}$ and $(0:1)\in\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb F_p}$ is identified.

On the other hand, the generic fiber is the subscheme of
$$\mathbb A^1_{\mathbb Q_p}\times\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb Q_p}$$
defined by $xX_1=pY_1$. Here, there is an isomorphism
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb A^1_{\mathbb Q_p}&\xrightarrow\sim Z(xX_1-pY_1)\\
a&\mapsto(a,(p:a)).
\end{align*}$$

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.